# Split a string in R into rows and columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data set that looks similar to the sample below:

```
rows <- c('70150 Markers, Times, Places    72588 Times, Places, Things',
          '51256 Items, Shelves, Cats    99201 Widget, Places, Locations')
```

I need to split the strings to create useful features.  My expected output would be similar to:

```
Code        Item
70150       Markers, Times, Places
72588       Times, Places, Things
51256       Items, Shelves, Cats
99201       Widget, Places, Locations
```

I tried using

```
library(tidyverse)

rows <- c('70150 Markers, Times, Places    72588 Times, Places, Things',
          '51256 Items, Shelves, Cats    99201 Widget, Places, Locations')

rows %>% parse_number
```

to get the number, but that only gets the first numeric value in the string.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `separate_rows` to split the column created at the space before the digit, then `separate` into two columns at the first spaces

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = rows) %>%
     separate_rows(col1, sep="\\s+(?=[0-9])") %>%
     separate(col1, into = c("Code", "Item"), extra = 'merge')
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Code  Item                     
#  <chr> <chr>                    
#1 70150 Markers, Times, Places   
#2 72588 Times, Places, Things    
#3 51256 Items, Shelves, Cats     
#4 99201 Widget, Places, Locations
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're inclined on using base R, here's one way of doing it.

```
rows <- c('70150 Markers, Times, Places    72588 Times, Places, Things',
          '51256 Items, Shelves, Cats    99201 Widget, Places, Locations')

rows <- strsplit(rows, "   ")
rows <- sapply(rows, FUN = trimws, simplify = FALSE)
rows <- unlist(rows)

ptn <- "^(\\d+) (.*)$"
data.frame(Code = gsub(ptn, replacement = "\\1", x = rows),
           Item = gsub(ptn, replacement = "\\2", x = rows))

   Code                      Item
1 70150    Markers, Times, Places
2 72588     Times, Places, Things
3 51256      Items, Shelves, Cats
4 99201 Widget, Places, Locations
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on more than 2 spaces in `rows` and using `str_match` from `stringr` capture the information in two groups, the number part and the remaining part of the string.

```
new_rows <- unlist(strsplit(rows, '\\s{2,}'))
stringr::str_match(new_rows, "(\\d+)\\s*(.*)")[, -1]

#        [,1]    [,2]                       
#[1,] "70150" "Markers, Times, Places"   
#[2,] "72588" "Times, Places, Things"    
#[3,] "51256" "Items, Shelves, Cats"     
#[4,] "99201" "Widget, Places, Locations"
```

This returns a matrix, you can convert it to dataframe and assign proper column names if needed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative in base R is to use `strcapture`. You specify the pattern to identify columns and the prototype object that the split values should be inserted into. Since you have multiple values per vector element, you need to split that first (by multiple spaces).

```
pattern <- "([[:digit:]]+) (.*)"
proto <- data.frame(code = integer(), item = character())
strcapture(pattern, unlist(strsplit(rows, "\\s{2,}")), proto)
#    code                      item
# 1 70150    Markers, Times, Places
# 2 72588     Times, Places, Things
# 3 51256      Items, Shelves, Cats
# 4 99201 Widget, Places, Locations
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regextract <- function(x, pattern, perl = TRUE, invert = FALSE, ...) {
  m <- gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = perl, ...) # match results
  unlist(regmatches(x, m, invert = invert))
}

txt <- unlist(strsplit(rows, "\\s{2,}"))
patterns <- c(Code = "(\\d+)", Item = "([[:alpha:],\\s]+)")
out <- lapply(patterns, regextract, x = txt)
out <- lapply(out, trimws)
out <- do.call(cbind, out)

out 

Code    Item                       
[1,] "70150" "Markers, Times, Places"   
[2,] "72588" "Times, Places, Things"    
[3,] "51256" "Items, Shelves, Cats"     
[4,] "99201" "Widget, Places, Locations"
```